# Kswapd0 using 100% of CPU

Tags: ram, cpu

I've got a mini server running (L)ubuntu 14.04.3, kernel 3.4.39. Every once in a while, the process kswapd0 will use 100% of my CPU power, even though I only use about ~20% of my RAM at that time. There is no reason for kswapd0 to be running, let alone use that much of my CPU. I've already tried putting my vm.swappiness = 1, but unfortunately that didn't help.

There is a lot stuff on google about this problem, some dating back as far as 2010, but no real answer. What should I try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much RAM/swap do you have?

Comment: @Wilf, I have 1GB of RAM, and as far as I know no swap memory. Here is a picture of the output of the `top` commmand. In the top you can see how much RAM and swap I have. [Picture](http://i.imgur.com/sc3VJ70.png)

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found the answer, it turns out that most of my RAM was full of cached memory. If you set up a cronjob to clear cached memory every hour or so kswapd0 never appears again.

Answer (score 0):

It still has a process to check if there's any swap. To reduce it, you'll need to set your swappiness -

edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` as root, then change (or add)

```
vm.swappiness = 0
```